# Detecting Camera Flash with respect to Retina Flash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

We are using `UIImagePickerController` with our custom UI buttons. I have encountered a problem in which I couldn't find an API to detect Retina Flash. [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/VideoRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html) I found has the same problem.

Here's everything I found to check on Flash. As you can see theres no way to know is iPhone 6S has Retina Flash when using rear camera.

```
- (void)flashTest {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:_delegate.imagePickerController.cameraDevice]) {
        NSLog(@"isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = NO");
    }

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasFlash]) {
        NSLog(@"device hasFlash - YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"device hasFlash - NO");
    }

    if ([device isFlashActive]) {
        NSLog(@"Flash is not active");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Flash IS active");
    }

    if ([device isFlashModeSupported:AVCaptureFlashModeOn]) {
        NSLog(@"Flash mode supported YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Flash Mode not supproted.");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
iPod Touch Back
----------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = YES  
device hasFlash - YES  
Flash IS active  
Flash mode supported YES  

iPod Touch Front
----------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = NO  
device hasFlash - YES  
Flash IS active  
Flash mode supported YES  

iPhone 6S Back
----------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = YES  
device hasFlash - YES  
Flash IS active
Flash mode supported YES  

iPhone 6S Front
---------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = NO  
device hasFlash - YES  
Flash IS active
Flash mode supported YES

iPad Air Back
--------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = NO
device hasFlash - NO
Flash IS active
Flash Mode not supproted.

iPad Air Front
--------------
isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice = NO
device hasFlash - NO
Flash IS active
Flash Mode not supproted.
```

Documentation says.

> ### Retina Flash
>
> On supported devices, the display brightness can briefly increase to 3 times its usual maximum illuminance for use as a flash for the front-facing camera. When using this feature, the display also varies its color output to achieve the same effect as the True Tone flash of the back-facing camera. No separate API controls this feature—on supported devices, the AVCaptureDevice hasFlash property reflects the availability of Retina Flash for the front-facing camera. As with the back-facing camera, you can use the isFlashModeSupported: and flashMode properties to control the flash.

I filed a bug. http://www.openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4941073017208832

**Update**

I check for both Rear and Back cameras. I call `flashTest` twice: initially and after I flip camera in my custom UI with following code.

```
_delegate.imagePickerController.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
```

**TL;DR;**
There's no way to determine is Flash available. With iPod Touch case `hasFlash` returns `YES` even if I using Front Camera, `isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice` returns correct `YES`, `NO` for iPod Back Front respectively but on iPhone 6S it returns the same `YES`, `NO` although it has Retina Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Retina flash is only for front camera not for rear camera. Here you checked it for rear camera. So, it returns no.

Comment: Please use the setter method to set cameraDevice property of imagePicker  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [picker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your active camera device is front camera and it has flash available, that means the device has Retina Flash, because only Retina device from 6s onwards has front camera flash. Code is here -

```
-(AVCaptureDevice *)getFrontCameraDevice
{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices)
    {
        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront)
        {
            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    return captureDevice;
}

-(BOOL)hasRetinaFlash:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront && device.hasFlash) {
         return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You night be right, unfortunately it is going to be a while until I can test this solution. I appreciate if anyone will find this solution working, please let me know and I will accept this.

Comment: Well i am doing an app called Raydium, you will see that soon in App store. This app artificially adjusts exposure and iso in low light and uses a simulation of Apple's retina devices front screen flash if not available, so i am using the same code i have pasted here and its working for me.

Comment: I have slightly changed it in my code to a category to make it look good and easily assessable ,which looks like my another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "AVCaptureDevice+Extension.h"

@implementation AVCaptureDevice (Extension)

-(BOOL)hasRetinaFlash
{
    if(self.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront && self.hasFlash) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

-(BOOL)isFrontCamera
{
    return (self.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront);
}


-(BOOL)isBackCamera
{
    return (self.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack);
}
```